# Change ssh default port in hadoop multi cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hbase

My Hadoop muti node cluster has 3 nodes, one namenode and two datanodes, I am using Hbase for storing data, due to some reasons I want to change default ssh port number which I know how to do, but if I change that, what configuration changes I will have to make in hadoop and hbase?

I saw [link](http://blog.dongjinleekr.com/changing-port-no-of-hadoop-cluster/) , this link just explains the change in configuration for hadoop, but I think configuration of Hbase, Zookeper and Yarn also needs to be changed. Am I right? If yes, what changes I need to do in hadoop and hbase?

Hadoop verison 2.7.1

HBase version 1.0.1.1

Help Appreciated :)

Comment: This question belongs on http://serverfault.com, anyways

Comment: Are you saying that you are facing brute force attack and due to that you want to change the ssh port and if you do that change is there any configuration changes do you have to make to your already configured Hadoop and Hbase cluster?

Comment: @Wazzzy yes, so in this case which file I need to change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSH isn't a Hadoop managed configuration, and therefore has nothing to do with Spark, Hbase, Zookeper or Yarn other than adding new nodes to the cluster and inter-process communication.

You'll have to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on every node to change any SSH related settings. Then restart all the Hadoop services as well as `sshd`.

The related line is

```
Port 22
```

Change the port number, then do

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

---

In `hadoop-env.sh` there is the `HADOOP_SSH_OPTS` environment variable. I'm not really sure what it does, but you are welcome to try and set a port like so.

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p <num>"
```

---

Also not sure about this one, but in `hbase-env.sh`

```
export HBASE_SSH_OPTS="-p <num>"
```

---

Once done setting all the configs, restart the Hadoop services

```
stop-all.sh
start-all.sh
```

Comment: # Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
# export HBASE_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HBASE_CONF_DIR" , these are the ssh option available in hbase-env.sh

Comment: Keyword is extra. It's just the additional flags to pass to an ssh command. You asked how to change the port for ssh, and editing the sshd_config is how

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Hadoop consists of a cluster of machines, each with their own ssh configuration which hadoop does not manage on its own. In order to add a node to the cluster, you must have ssh access to that machine for inter-process communication. If you change the port while the machine is in the cluster, **only then** will you need to change some hadoop configuration files

Comment: sorry if I am not able explain my issue. Yes I already have machine in a cluster.

Comment: Then why do you want to change the ssh port?

Comment: I have to change because one of the datanode server is frequently facing brute force attack

Comment: @PrashantPuri You are saying that you are facing brute force attack and due to that you want to change the ssh port and if you do that change is there any configuration changes do you have to make to your already configured Hadoop and Hbase cluster?

Comment: @Wazzzy yes, so in this case which file I need to change?

Comment: See updates - Basically you should have set the SSH port before you added the node to the cluster. It is more of a hassle to go around changing configurations afterwards.

Comment: @cricket_007. thanks, it helps me. sorry it take me time to reply.

Comment: @cricket_007 It takes me time because I setup demo cluster of hadoop with same configuration to avoid conflicts in production server, and then i change port number. Thanks :)