# spark running at the port 249

Tags: apache-spark, ssh, port

```
sbin$ start-all.sh
```

I input this command then I got the below message.
I use port 249 not 22.
Port 22 is prohibited.
I'm connecting to the server using **putty**.
How can I fix this problem?

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master running as process 6211.  Stop it first.
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006317/apache-spark-how-to-change-the-port-the-spark-driver-listens-to

Comment: The Hadoop start-all command requires SSH connections to communicate with all services... Your localhost appears not to be running SSH server

Comment: Or you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225126/2308683

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have solved it.
Follow these steps maybe can solve your problem :

1. vi conf/spark-env.sh
2. add these `export SPARK_SSH_OPTS="-p 249"`
3. rerun `start-all.sh`